# "Undefined symbol" error when running NetworkManager

Tags: network-manager, 20.04

**Settings - Network:**

```
Oops something has gone wrong. Please contact your software vendor.
NetworkManager needs to be running.
```

[image]

```
~$ NetworkManager
NetworkManager: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl-gnutls.so.4: undefined symbol: gnutls_srp_allocate_client_credentials, version GNUTLS_3_4
```

**sudo service network-manager restart**

```
~$ sudo service network-manager restart
Job for NetworkManager.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status NetworkManager.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

**systemctl status NetworkManager.service**

```
~$ systemctl status NetworkManager.service
● NetworkManager.service - Network Manager
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/NetworkManager.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2020-06-18 16:49:27 MSK; 21min ago
       Docs: man:NetworkManager(8)
    Process: 5827 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon (code=exited, status=127)
   Main PID: 5827 (code=exited, status=127)

Jun 18 16:49:27 galls-Sys systemd[1]: NetworkManager.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Jun 18 16:49:27 galls-Sys systemd[1]: Stopped Network Manager.
Jun 18 16:49:27 galls-Sys systemd[1]: NetworkManager.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Jun 18 16:49:27 galls-Sys systemd[1]: NetworkManager.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jun 18 16:49:27 galls-Sys systemd[1]: Failed to start Network Manager.
```

**journalctl -xe**

```
~$ journalctl -xe
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Automatic restarting of the unit NetworkManager.service has been scheduled, as the result for
-- the configured Restart= setting for the unit.
Jun 18 17:19:43 galls-Sys systemd[1]: Stopped Network Manager.
-- Subject: A stop job for unit NetworkManager.service has finished
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- A stop job for unit NetworkManager.service has finished.
-- 
-- The job identifier is 6353 and the job result is done.
Jun 18 17:19:43 galls-Sys systemd[1]: NetworkManager.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Jun 18 17:19:43 galls-Sys systemd[1]: NetworkManager.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
-- Subject: Unit failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- The unit NetworkManager.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
Jun 18 17:19:43 galls-Sys systemd[1]: Failed to start Network Manager.
-- Subject: A start job for unit NetworkManager.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- A start job for unit NetworkManager.service has finished with a failure.
-- 
-- The job identifier is 6353 and the job result is failed.
Jun 18 17:19:48 galls-Sys sudo[8191]:   galls : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/galls ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/sbin/service network-manager restart
Jun 18 17:19:48 galls-Sys sudo[8191]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Jun 18 17:19:48 galls-Sys systemd[1]: NetworkManager.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Jun 18 17:19:48 galls-Sys systemd[1]: NetworkManager.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
-- Subject: Unit failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- The unit NetworkManager.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
Jun 18 17:19:48 galls-Sys systemd[1]: Failed to start Network Manager.
-- Subject: A start job for unit NetworkManager.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- A start job for unit NetworkManager.service has finished with a failure.
-- 
-- The job identifier is 6440 and the job result is failed.
Jun 18 17:19:48 galls-Sys sudo[8191]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Jun 18 17:19:54 galls-Sys /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2576]: (EE) client bug: timer event4 debounce: scheduled expiry is in the past (-0ms), your system >
Jun 18 17:19:54 galls-Sys /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2576]: (EE) client bug: timer event4 debounce short: scheduled expiry is in the past (-13ms), your >
Jun 18 17:19:59 galls-Sys /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2576]: (EE) client bug: timer event4 debounce short: scheduled expiry is in the past (-12ms), your >
Jun 18 17:20:11 galls-Sys /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2576]: (EE) client bug: timer event4 debounce short: scheduled expiry is in the past (-11ms), your >
lines 3103-3151/3151 (END)
```

**ifconfig**

```
~$ ifconfig
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/command-not-found", line 28, in <module>
    from CommandNotFound import CommandNotFound
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/CommandNotFound.py", line 19, in <module>
    from CommandNotFound.db.db import SqliteDatabase
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/db/db.py", line 3, in <module>
    import sqlite3
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/sqlite3/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from sqlite3.dbapi2 import *
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/sqlite3/dbapi2.py", line 27, in <module>
    from _sqlite3 import *
ImportError: /usr/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: sqlite3_enable_load_extension
```

Possible to fix it without network connection?

Comment: Have you updated your ubuntu recently or installed some packages manually (i.e not from repo) ? The **symbol lookup error** is possibly caused by a version mismatch.Here is the [libcurl3-gnutls](https://drive.google.com/file/d/12j2DjzTKPbdmXgfQVsrKthD11IQjQSae/view?usp=sharing) package that I downloaded from the newest ubuntu repo in . Try installing it manually via **dpkg** to see if it can solve the problem.Please tell me the results to decide whether it needs reinstalling the whole **Network-Manager** package with all dependencies or not.

Comment: @ParsaMousavi, Hello! `sudo apt install libcurl3-gnutls` - libcurl3-gnutls is already the newest version (7.68.0-1ubuntu2). How to use it to solve my problem?

Comment: This command in my system ```nm -D /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl-gnutls.so.4 | grep "gnutls\_srp\_allocate\_client\_credentials"``` yields ```U gnutls_srp_allocate_client_credentials``` . The letter **U** means **Undefined** which indicates that the library uses that symbol but it's not defined anywhere. But I don't have that problem when I run **NetworkManager**. I'm totally confused .

Comment: I think other than re-installing ubuntu  you have two options : 1) purging the NetworkManager entirely and re-installing it via deb packages with all dependencies.( you can get the deb packages in a live system (since you haven't network connection in that situation) via ```sudo apt reinstall -d network-manager``` and that will put all the packages in the **/var/cache/apt/archives/** directory.Then install those manually.) and 2) You can compile and install [GnuTLS](https://gitlab.com/gnutls/gnutls/) and [Curl](https://github.com/curl/curl) manually to get a **libcurl-gnutls**.

Comment: But note that for compiling the **libcurl** with GnuTLS as the backend , you have to use the options `--without-ssl --with-gnutls` for the **./configure** command of **libcurl**. Sorry if the options I put in front of you is a little cumbersome but I've never encountered such a problem. The package version on your system is exactly the same as the package I've posted. So it's confusing.

Comment: @ParsaMousavi i copy network manager deb. Purge it from system. Install again. Is no effect.

Answer (score 2):

I ran quite as much in the same problem yesterday. My Kubuntu 20.10 notebook (Thinkpad T460) was idling with screen lock enabled and when I relogged in, KDE failed to resume and network was gone.

Both ifconfig and network-manager failed with the same error messages and I had a nasty digital garbage block in my syslog.

After several hours of research in the net the box is working again - kind of.

I forced a fsck for the next reboot

```
sudo tune2fs -c 1 /dev/vgkubuntu/root
```

Afer the reboot I deleted some libs assuming they were corrupted in the incdent

```
cd /usr/local/lib

sudo rm libgnutls.so.30 libsqlite3.so.0

cd /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/

sudo rm libcurl-gnutls.so.4.6.0
```

Your version numbers may vary.

Then manual reinstall

```
cd /var/cache/apt/archives/

sudo dpkg -i libsqlite3-0_3.31.1-4ubuntu0.2_amd64.deb 

sudo dpkg -i libgnutls30_3.6.13-2ubuntu1.3_amd64.deb
```

Your version numbers may vary, use the latest.

That made my network manager and other tools able to start again.

But I have to connect the wlan now manually by calling wpa_supplicant and dhclient .

Update: I could track it down to Filezilla Client, because my ubuntu server started the same behaviour just after I installed FZ.
I have logged in a ticket under
https://trac.filezilla-project.org/ticket/12426#ticket
Filezilla resolved by saying that you should never install Filezilla Client in system dirs but in an own space - such as `/opt/Filezilla` - this was novel to me.

Comment: Addendum: after reinstalling plasma-nm and network-manager and a lot of reboots the system behaves normal again.

Comment: Thanks a lot for posting this, I was pulling my hair until I have found this thread. Exactly the same issue with Filezilla.

Answer (score 0):

By any chance you used aircrack recently? If yes, problem might be wireless card being in monitoring mode.

Try using `sudo airmon-ng stop wlan0`.
It might be wlan0 or wlan0mon, you can confirm with `ifconfig` command

Once this is done, run `service network-manager restart`.