# Upgrade Ubuntu system files from Live CD reinstall to encrypted LUKS partition

Tags: 20.04, luks, reinstall

I boot from Live CD and select Try Ubuntu. Now I need to find my SSD encrypted volume.

When i back to normal boot i check previously

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

give me lot of loop devices and

```
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 238,49 Gib ..
Disk model ..
...

Device                 Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1   ...   243M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p2   ...   858M Linux filesystem
/dev/nvme0n1p3   ... 237,4G Linux filesystem
```

Then i must mount my LUKS partition to re-install Ubuntu on top.
When i boot from Live CD what command i must use to mount (what mount point) my encrypted volume?
Its save to install then Ubuntu above?

Comment: Can you boot into your encrypted system? In that case I think it is easier to get the system files you want to upgrade (from the CD drive, if you cannot access the internet). If you cannot boot into your encrypted system, it will be much more difficult. I would restore the whole system from a backup, (I hope you have a backup). Otherwise, let us hope that a real guru, who knows about LVM and LUKS encryption will read this and chip in.

Comment: You can mount your LUKS device with **cryptsetup luksOpen** as stated [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/182422/388589)

Comment: @sudodus, Yes i can boot to my encrypted system, but they have no internet access. I create on my another system Live USB stick. But I dint know how to upgrade sys files when my main encrypted system is up. Is no autorun and interface which provide me run Ubuntu restore or recovery install.

Comment: What system files do you want to upgrade? If you have the corresponding program package (a .deb file), you should be able to use `sudo dpkg -i filename.deb`

Comment: @sudodus I don,t know which files, my system today is lost network at all. I see my network only from Live USB. I cant fix it. My last hope to reinstall Ubuntu above.

Comment: Since you can run your system, I suggest that you **backup** your personal files, the whole home directory or at least the files, that you cannot afford to lose. Backup before you start tampering with the system, because you might make it impossible to boot, and maybe difficult to open, unless you have the key to open the LUKS container according the @ParsaMousavi's advice.

Comment: If you want to solve [that network-manager](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1251580/undefined-symbol-error-when-running-networkmanager) problem via a live medium , you can first remove the **netowrk-manager** package in your ubuntu installation , then copy all the files and folders pertaining to **network-manager** from the live medium to your ubuntu LUKS partition via `sudo dpkg-query -L network-manager | xargs cp -r /ubuntu/mount/point `.

Comment: @ParsaMousavi, I don't understand this solution `cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sda1 crypted_sda1` .. Why i must use `/dev/sda1, I already have /dev/sda1 in my system. I not so familiar with mount  and devices then i ask directly with my devices list: what i must mount and to what point?! To do not lost my data when reinstall.

Comment: @ParsaMousavi, I already purge and reinstall network manager. Is no effect.

Comment: You can use this for example : `cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/nvme0n1p3  ubuntu_enc ; mount /dev/mapper/ubuntu_enc /mnt` . Then your ubuntu partition would be mounted in the **/mnt** partition.

Comment: I think the last resort before the re-installation is to purge and re-install the **libcurl3-gnutls** package which caused the problem.

Comment: @ParsaMousavi reinstall of **libcurl3-gnutls** isn't help. I try to reinstall Ubuntu above old encrypted partition. But I don't understand what is the mount point for `/dev/nvme0n1p2   ...   858M Linux filesystem`? I setup mounted encrypted **ubuntu_enc** as root /, and `/dev/nvme0n1p1   ...   243M EFI System` as **efi**, but dont know how to detect purpose of `/dev/nvme0n1p2`.. Looks like its not swap, maybe it something connecting to LUKS encryption?

Comment: @mature It's maybe a mount point for your **/home** for example . I don't know.You can mount it manually and see their contents via the aforementioned method.